# Mysql resets primary key to the last deleted record after mysql server restart

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

Hy!
I have the following stupid question?
First an example to understand my point of view.
I have a mysql db, Innodb tables with foreign keys between them,
I currently work on a localhost machine
When I delete the last inserted record from a table let's say with primary auto-increment key set to
100 then the next primary key given by mysql is 101 but if I restart the mysql server (Apache server) then in the same table the primary key for the next record is reset to 100.
I have to mention that I set a trigger for the table I deleted the record from, to copy the deleted record to archive table before delete.
Now after mysql server was restarted if a new record is inserted it will get the primary key 100,and when I try to delete it a conflict appears because in the archive table there is already a primary key 100.
I have to keep the references between deleted key.
Now this happens only if mysql server is restarted.
The question is if this problem can be solved in case let's say that after the web application is deployed to a shared server host a server restart appears(I suppose).

I want to mention that the data base is moe complex the one table. I absolutely need to keep the integrity between archive tables after data is moved.

Comment: Found an ancient bug report on this. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=727 the last post has some workaround for it. And someone submitted a patch here http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=199